# How to compress HTTPS traffic?

Tags: ssl, https, compression

I have a problem with compressing HTTPS.
Everything works for **HTTP** with a one rule in .htaccess:

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

If I add second rule to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, the compression stops working:
Check GZIP compression says GZIP is not enabled :(

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Versions:

```
/etc/redhat-release:CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
/usr/local/cpanel/version:11.60.0.35
/var/cpanel/envtype:kvm
CPANEL=release
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (cPanel)
Server built:   Jan  4 2017 14:51:03
ea-php-cli Copyright 2016 cPanel, Inc.
PHP 5.6.29 (cli) (built: Jan  4 2017 15:08:12)
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.34, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (cPanel)
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: Turning on https shouldn't matter. Where are you seeing that gzip is not enabled?

Comment: @BazzaDP openssl s_client  -connect example.com:443

Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE

    Protocol  : TLSv1

Answer (score 4):

From the comments, it appears you are talking about HTTPS compression as returned by openssl s_client command:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
<snip>
Compression: NONE
</snip>
```

This is nothing to do with Gzip compression on each resource as used to reduce the size of large items (usually text based items like HTML, CSS and Javascript), but is an extra set of compression at the SSL/TLS level. It is recommended to NOT use compression at an SSL/TLS level due the [CRIME attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME_(security_exploit)) published in 2012. So it's quite expected to report that as No. In fact you should be worried if it's set to Yes.

Gzip body compression for each configured resource-type should still be enabled under HTTPS with your original config, as you will see in your browser developer tools Network tab (press F12 to open these in most browsers).

Comment: You are absolutely right.
I forgot to add <?php
        ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
      ?>  to .php files, hence all gzip checkers said no compressions.
Now the website is flying :)
Thank you!